# Why does Register become Registration (no e)?

Tags: spelling, morphology

Why does the English word Register become Registration, with the second 'e' being removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register and Registration share linguistic roots, but come to English in different ways. Register comes via Middle English "registre" from Medieval Latin "regstrum"

Registration comes more directly from Latin as "registrate" + "ion"

So the reason one has the E and the other doesn't has to do with how they came into English.

Additionally, note that the E is unstressed (which in English is reduced), so when you add the additional syllables, the sound disappears entirely. This appears in other words too.